# Is it possible to use alternate delimiters for awk's gsub function?

Tags: regex, awk, gsub

Consider the following substitution in [`awk`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html).

```
echo 'hello/bar/goo'  | awk '{gsub(/\//,"foo"); print}'
```

The output is the following.

```
hellofoobarfoogoo
```

Observe that we had to escape the `/` in the first argument to `gsub` because `/` is the default delimiter of the regex in awk's `gsub` function.

Considering the fact that we could solve the same problem in `sed` with a change of delimiter as below, I wonder whether the same is possible with `gsub`.

```
echo 'hello/bar/goo'  | sed 's!/!foo!g'
```

I have tried both of the following, but they result in syntax errors.

```
echo 'hello/bar/goo'  | awk '{gsub(!/!,"foo"); print}'                                                                                                         
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(!/!,"foo"); print}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:2: {gsub(!/!,"foo"); print}
awk: cmd. line:2:                         ^ unexpected newline or end of string

echo 'hello/bar/goo'  | awk '{gsub(|/|,"foo"); print}'
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(|/|,"foo"); print}
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {gsub(|/|,"foo"); print}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ unterminated regexp
```

Is there some option I can set in `awk` to allow alternate delimiters for `gsub`?

If so, what is the set of allowable alternate delimiters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use double quotes as delimiter.

```
echo 'hello/bar/goo'  | awk '{gsub("/","foo"); print}'
```

But careful when dealing with the backslash, since you need to use four backslashes in-order to match a single backslash.

```
$ echo 'hello/bar\goo' | awk '{gsub("\\\\","foo"); print}'
hello/barfoogoo
```

Comment: I will accept this answer because it certainly solves my problem. However, just curious, is this the only alternate delimiter? (I noticed the manual I linked did not even mention this one.)

Comment: That's it. If you need alternate delimiters and a higher-level language, maybe look at Perl. There are tools `s2p` and `a2p` to convert `sed` and Awk scripts to Perl scripts. (These says, perhaps you should also consider Python and/or Ruby.)

Comment: @merlin2011 - to be clear, `/` is the **ONLY** regexp delimiter that awk supports. You can however use a variable or a string in a regexp context and then awk will convert that to a regexp before using it as such. So when you see `"foo"` in a regexp context, the `"`s are not regexp delimiters they are string delimiters and awk is converting the string to a regexp because of the context that string is being used in (e.g. the first arg to `gsub()`. Try `echo 'x' | awk '/foo/'` and `echo 'x' | awk '"foo"'` and you will see that `"` is not a regexp delimiter and look up static vs dynamic regexps.

Answer (score 0):

Only delimiter for regex in `awk` is `/`, but you can as Avinash showed, search for a string `"something"`. No other option possible.